# Devrait-on traduire les questions anglaises ? Should we translate questions written in English?

Tags: discussion, questions

Devrions-nous modifier les questions écrites uniquement en anglais et ajouter une traduction (française) sous celle-ci?

Should we edit questions asked solely in English to add a French translation underneath?

Answer (score 6):

La question revient de temps en temps. Dès le début du site, il y a eu un débat sur [quelle devrait en être la langue principale](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/quelle-est-la-langue-principale-du-site-what-is-the-primary-language-of-the-sit). Avec le temps, il apparaît que la langue dominante est le français, mais qu'il y a aussi un créneau pour les questions et réponses en anglais. J'invite à parcourir l'étiquette [language](/questions/tagged/language).

Je pense que c'est une bonne idée de traduire tous les messages en français, mais ce n'est pas réaliste. Bien sûr, toute personne souhaitant contribuer est la bienvenue.

Also: 
[Translating monolingual answers to "important" questions](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/translating-monolingual-answers-to-important-questions)